# Distribution of the output of AWGN channel

Tags: discrete-signals, gaussian, multi-channel

$$\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{W}$$

$\mathbf{X}$ is input, an $n$-dimension equiprobable vector in a finite subset of complex space $\mathcal{A}^n \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ with norm $\sqrt{\rho n}$ (constant power), e.g. BPSK, QPSK, [8-PSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying#Higher-order_PSK), etc.

$\mathbf{W}$ is circularly complex Gaussian vector $\mathcal{CN}(0, \mathbf{I}_n)$.

I want to know the closed form of $P_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y})$. And if possible, the $P_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y})$ induced by the [QAM modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_amplitude_modulation) of $\mathbf{X}$ (identical average power).

---

I can numerically calculate 
$$P_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y}) = \sum_\mathbf{x}P_{\mathbf{Y}|\mathbf{X}}(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x})P_{\mathbf{X}}(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_\mathbf{x}P_{\mathbf{Y}|\mathbf{X}}(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x})\frac{1}{|\mathcal{A}|^n} = \frac{1}{|\mathcal{A}|^n} \sum_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{A}^n} \frac{1}{\pi^n}e^{-\left\Vert\mathbf{y-x}\right\Vert ^2} \tag{1}$$

where $|\mathcal{A}|$ is the cardinality of set $\mathcal{A}$. But I want to avoid $\sum_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{A}^n}$ because it is cumbersome.

---

If $\mathcal{A} = \mathbb{C}$ I can use the spherical symmetry trick that 
$$P_{\mathbf{Y}}(\mathbf{y}) = \frac{1}{S} \times P_{\left\Vert\mathbf{Y}\right\Vert^2}(\left\Vert\mathbf{y}\right\Vert^2) \tag{2}$$

where $S$ is the surface of n-dimension complex sphere with radius $\sqrt{\rho n}$ and $P_{\left\Vert\mathbf{Y}\right\Vert^2}(\left\Vert\mathbf{y}\right\Vert^2)$ is [noncentral $\chi$-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom and noncentrality parameter $n \rho$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution). Thus I have a closed form of the distribution of $\mathbf{Y}$.

I think this must be a classical problem, it would be great if someone gives me a hint or points out a paper.

Comment: Since QAM modulation has a finite number of constellation points, I think you just expand the sum into M terms (M is # of constellation points), giving a closed form expression?

Comment: Are the elements in each vector iid? Because in the coding schemes you mentioned (BPSK, QPSK, 8-PSK), each element of the vectors belong to the alphabet, and not the entire vector itself. 
If the vector elements are iid, then it would simplify things.

Answer (score 1):

I see this question is open for a long time, I am not sure if I understand it correctly.

### PDF of the symbols

The first probability is a $P_{\mathbf{Y}}: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, you are not considering phase noise, the probability  of the $n$ symbols are identically distributed, let's say with $P_{\mathbf{Y}_i}: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, since the joint probability of independent variables are the product of the individual variables this distribution can be written as

$$P_{\mathbf{Y}}(y) = \prod_{i=1}^{N}P_{\mathbf{Y}_i}(y_i)$$

Where $P_{\mathbf{Y}_i}(y_i) = \sum_{x\in \mathbf{X}_i}p_{\mathbf{X}}(x_i) e^{-||y_i - x_i||^2}/\pi$ which leads to

$$P_{\mathbf{Y}}(y) = \frac{1}{\pi^N}\prod_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{x\in \mathbf{X}_i} p_{\mathbf{X}}(x_i) e^{-||y_i - x_i||^2}$$

The term $p_{\mathbb{X}}(x_i)$ can be used to model probabilistic shaping, but for the original quesiton it will probably be a the inverse of the number of symbols in the constellation $1/c = 1/|\mathbf{X}_i|$, that by it's turn is the same for all symbols, thus

$$P_{\mathbf{Y}}(y) = \frac{1}{c^N\pi^N}\prod_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{x\in \mathbf{X}_i} p_{\mathbf{X}}(x_i) e^{-||y_i - x_i||^2}$$

The complex of evaluating this will be $c N$ exponentials. The number of additions and multiplications will be linear in $cN$ as well, differently from the initial formula that would compute $c^N$ terms.

For some applications you may want the logarithm of that expression, in such situations it is preferable to use the sum of logarithms

$$log\left(P_{\mathbf{Y}}(y)\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\log\left(\frac{1}{c \pi} \sum_{x\in \mathbf{X}_i} p_{\mathbf{X}}(x_i) e^{-||y_i - x_i||^2}\right)$$

All of this is valid for QAM modulation as well, and don't have the exponential number of terms in the initial formula.

### PDF of the energy

In the second part you mention the PDF of the energy of the symbols

That is the probability distribution of

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{N} \sum_{x_i \in \mathbf{X}_i} p_{\mathbf{X}_i}(x_i) ||x_i + w_i||^2$$

Assuming $w$ having a variance $\sigma$ for both real and imaginary parts, since the norm of a complex number $||a + 1j b||^2 = a^2 + b^2$, assuming uniform probability for the symbols in the constelation, we can divide the whole expression the symbols $\sigma$ (since the the formula is given for a covariance matrix being the identity). And the distribution of the energy will be of the form $\sum_{k=1}^{2N} X_{i}^2$ as assumed for the noncentral $\chi^2$ distribution with $2N$ degrees of freedom.

The noncentrality parameter given by

$$\lambda =\frac{N}{c \sigma^2} \sum_{x \in \mathbf{X}} ||x||^2$$

The number of degrees of freedom $k=2N$, because we separated real and imaginary parts.

Let $z$ be the energy of one sample, taking in to account that the $\chi^2$ distribution was normalized by dividing by the variance, the PDF of $z$ will be

$$p_{||\mathbf{Y}||^2}(z) = 
\frac{1}{2\sigma} e^{\left(\frac{z}{2\sigma} + \frac{\lambda}{2}\right)}
\left(\frac{z}{\lambda \sigma}\right)^{(N-1)/2}
I_{N-1}\left( \sqrt{\frac{\lambda z}{\sigma}}\right)
$$

**Note**:
In spite of being a closed formula it depends on the computation of $I_{\alpha}(x)$, a [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions), that for positive integer $\alpha$ and positive $x$ reduces to a series with rational coefficients in $x$, thus

$$ I_{N-1}\left( \sqrt{\frac{\lambda z}{\sigma}}\right) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\sqrt{\frac{\lambda z}{\sigma}}\right)^{2m+N-1}}{m!(m+N)!} $$